# Unable to save multiple text files in same folder (MacOS Swift Application)

Tags: swift, macos, text-files, saving-data

I am trying to save multiple text files in the same folder. So far I can save one text file into a generated folder in my document directory, but I cannot save more than one text file in that same folder.

```
 let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
            let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
            let docURL = URL(string: documentsDirectory)!
            let dataPath = docURL.appendingPathComponent("User_Notes")
```

// this is the folder name

```
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath.path) {
                do {
                    try
                        FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                    
                 //   try stringToWrite.write(to: &dataPath)
                    
                    try stringToWrite.write(toFile: "\(dataPath)/\(userNotes)).txt", atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                    
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            
            if error != nil {
                                                             
                print("Error saving user data.")
                                                             
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think if you print the string you're interpolating in the `.write(...)` line, you'll find it doesn't look exactly like you expect.

Comment: What's this?  Why do you want to add a file extension to a folder name?  let dataPath = docURL.appendingPathComponent("User_Notes")

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I figured it out!  My mistake was in the line: "if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath.path)". I was supposed to remove the exclamation point.